# MahApps.metro how to add icon to title bar left corner

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I seem to be having issue's getting a icon for my application to show up in the left corner of the window title bar. I already have one set for the program's .exe
But to no avail everything I have tried is not setting a seperate icon specifically for the title bar.  if you could help with some insight it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you add your icon to the root project solution folder then you can use this icon by setting the `Icon` property for the window.

```
Icon="mahapps.metro.logo2.ico"
```

[image]

Hope this helps.